# Color changing dots in 2D array based on time

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to coding but I have this idea for sort of a visual clock. I would like to represent how much time in the day has elapsed. I decided to create a grid of dots, each represents 10 seconds in the day. So a dot should change color every 10 seconds and this would progress one row at a time. I have managed to create the grid of 120 columns and 72 rows but I'm having issues correctly comparing the index of the grid to the time elapsed.

Here is my code so far,

```js
  function startTime() { //Start clock
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
  var currentseconds = Math.floor(((h * 3600) + (m * 60) + s) / 10);
  change(currentseconds);
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = currentseconds;
}
//------------------
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //drawing object

var cwidth = 500; //define canvas width

var cols = 120; // define the number of columns 
var rows = 72; // define the numnber of rows 

canvas.width = cwidth; //set canvas width
canvas.height = cwidth * (rows / cols); //adjust canvas height to be proportional to the number of rows

ctx.fillStyle = "#373737";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //draw and fill rectangle full size of canvas
//------------------

setInterval(change, 1000); //run change function every 1 second
function change(seconds) { //create 2d array grid of dots
var currentseconds = seconds;
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      var x = i * (cwidth / cols) + ((cwidth / cols) / 2); //spacing of columns
      var y = j * (cwidth / cols) + ((cwidth / cols) / 2); //spacing of rows

      if ([i][j] <= seconds) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      } // change colour of dots as time increases
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, (2 * Math.PI));
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill(); // draw dots
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #424949;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -51%)
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime(), change()">
  <div id="seconds"></div>
  <br>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Although this may not be your entire problem you are declaring `currentseconds` a second time inside the `startTime()` function. This is why when you access the global one you get undefined.

Comment: Thanks for that find, I fixed that now I think.  Only the top row fills on the grid and that's where my main problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script determines whether a given dot should be red with the comparison `if ([i][j] <= seconds)`. I am surprised that it works at all. The corresponding value of each dot if you are counting left to right, then top to bottom from the top left corner would be `i + j * cols`.

```js
function startTime() { //Start clock
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 10000);
  var currentseconds = Math.floor(((h * 3600) + (m * 60) + s) / 10);
  change(currentseconds);
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = currentseconds;
}
//------------------
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //drawing object

var cwidth = 500; //define canvas width

var cols = 120; // define the number of columns 
var rows = 72; // define the numnber of rows 

canvas.width = cwidth; //set canvas width
canvas.height = cwidth * (rows / cols); //adjust canvas height to be proportional to the number of rows

ctx.fillStyle = "#373737";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //draw and fill rectangle full size of canvas
//------------------

function change(seconds) { //create 2d array grid of dots
var currentseconds = seconds;
ctx.fillStyle = "#373737";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      var x = i * (cwidth / cols) + ((cwidth / cols) / 2); //spacing of columns
      var y = j * (cwidth / cols) + ((cwidth / cols) / 2); //spacing of rows

      if (i+j*cols <= seconds) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      } // change colour of dots as time increases
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, (2 * Math.PI));
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill(); // draw dots
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #424949;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -51%)
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="seconds"></div>
  <br>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

EDIT after comment:
I have edited the script to fix the blinking. These are the problems that caused it:

- The `change` function was called several times. It got called from the `startTime` (which is correct, as you are passing the time), then immediately from the following `html` command (incorrect, no time was passed), then form the `setInterval` (again incorrect, no time was passed).
- The `setInterval` was not necessary. You have a call to `change` from `startTime` every 10 seconds.
- I have also cleared the rectangle in every iteration of `change`. If you paint on top of the previous paint, you will see small changes in color and thickness.

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you! Not sure if you can also help with the blinking that occurs. I seem to have my `setInterval` in the wrong place since it redraws the whole grid every second. I just want it to run that `if (i+j*cols <= seconds)` statement every second.

Comment: I have modified the script and updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appriciate the help you've given me. Also thanks for explaining where I went wrong, I definitely know a bit more now.